# Como destruir un Token en Asp .Net Jwt

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tokens

Tengo un `Token` con la librería `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;` El cual funciona correctamente peto tengo la siguiente duda y el como lo podría hacer el `Token` contiene una variable `Expires` el tiempo de vida del `Token`, median `Jquery` ejecuto una función de inactividad del usuario para que termine la sesión del usuario, pero me di cuenta que aunque mediante de `Jquery` le configure bastante tiempo de actividad el `Token` respeta su tiempo de vida, lo que quiero lograr es como podría destruir el `Token` cuando el tiempo de inactividad que tengo por medio de `Jquery` se cumpla, y asi se finalize la sesión, ¿Como podria lograrlo?

Token:

```
public class AuthHelper
{
    public AuthHelper() {
    }   
    public string Auth(tbl_personaModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var TokenString = "";
            if (model.Identificacion != 0 && model.Clave != null)
            {
                var TokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var TokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim( "Correo", model.Identificacion.ToString()),
                        new Claim( "Clave", model.Clave )
                    }),
                    Audience = "https://127.0.0.1",
                    Issuer = "https://127.0.0.1",
                    Expires = now.AddSeconds(60),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsecretsecret")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                };
                SecurityToken Token = TokenHandler.CreateToken(TokenDescriptor);
                TokenString = TokenHandler.WriteToken(Token);
            }
            return TokenString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public bool ValidateToken(string tokenString)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenString);

            //var tokenString2 = tokenHandler.WriteToken(StringToken);
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            var param = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                ValidIssuer = "https://127.0.0.1",
                ValidAudience = "https://127.0.0.1",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                LifetimeValidator = LifetimeValidator,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsecretsecret")),
            };

            var claims = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenString, param, out validatedToken);

            return true;
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch(SecurityTokenInvalidLifetimeException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // COMPRUEBA LA CADUCIDAD DEL TOKEN
    public bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore,
                                  DateTime? expires,
                                  SecurityToken securityToken,
                                  TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var valid = false;

        if ((expires.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow < expires)
            && (notBefore.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow > notBefore))
        { valid = true; }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Jquery:

```
let timeoutInMiliseconds = 60000;
let timeoutId;
function resetTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    startTimer();
}
function startTimer() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(doInactive, timeoutInMiliseconds);
}
function doInactive() {
        let RedirectUrl = '/Home/Index/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: '/CreditoWizard/ValidarToken/',
            context: document.body,
            data: { StringToken: $('#lblToken').text() },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Opsss!',
                        text: 'Por falta de actividad su sesión ha caducado, Gracias.',
                        customClass: {
                            container: 'container-class',
                            popup: 'popupAlert',
                            header: 'header-class',
                            title: 'titleAlert',
                            closeButton: 'close-button-class',
                            icon: 'icon-class',
                            image: 'image-class',
                            content: 'perzonalizaAlert',
                            input: 'input-class',
                            actions: 'actions-class',
                            confirmButton: 'confirm-button-class',
                            cancelButton: 'cancel-button-class',
                            footer: 'footer-class'
                        },
                        confirmButtonColor: "#df402b",
                        imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
                        imageWidth: 400,
                        imageHeight: 200,
                        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                        allowEscapeKey: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            window.location.href = RedirectUrl;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //debugger;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log("Error has occurred..", xhr);
            }
        });
}
function setupTimers() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    startTimer();
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult ValidarToken(string StringToken)
    {
        try
        {
            TokenHelper = new AuthHelper();
            bool ResultJson = TokenHelper.ValidateToken(StringToken);
            return Json(ResultJson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te hace falta un metodo para cerrar sesion, del lado del usuario busca donde estas almacenando el token ese debes borrarlo y si tambien del lado del servidor estas conservando valores de la sesion esos debes eliminarlos.

Comment: Como tal, mi sesión es el `Token` activo, como tal no tengo un `Login` propiamente dicho, no se si me hago entender.

Comment: Pero es necesario que agregues una nueva accion en el servidor para indicar que tu sesion termino, esa accion la llama el usuario o cuando ha cumplido su tiempo de inactividad. En esta accion puedes crear un token ya expirado y sin permisos para cuando el usuario quiera realizar alguna accion su nuevo token es invalido. exires=now; sin claims.

Comment: Es posible que me des un ejemplo de como hacerlo, ya que realmente no sé le como.

Answer (score 0):

Pues en si el token solo lo tienes del lado del usuario final,
si solo quieres dejar de usarlo en tu metodo:

```
function doInactive() {
 $('#lblToken').text(""); //reemplazas el valor del token por el valor vacio
//redirect url.
}
```

ahora el token no es como una sesion es un permiso que puede ser usado hasta que
expire, lo mas recomendable es que del lado del Servidor, manejes si un usuario
esta en sesion o no es decir ya sea en un cache o en Base de datos puedes guardar
que dicho usuario o token tenga abierta una sesion. Si el usuario por inactividad o
porque decidio cerrar la sesion en tu servidor guardas que ya se cerro la sesion asi
cuando un usuario cualquiera quiera reutilizar ese token debera volver a identificarse
y obtener un nuevo token ( y por tanto una nueva sesion.)